# SizeToFit on a UIScrollView's content size

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

A UIView has a SizeToFit method that will make the UIView fit all of it's subviews. Is there anything like that, which will just return the size that it calculates and not modify any view's frame.

I have several subviews on a UIScrollView and I want to do SizeToFit on the scroll view's contentSize, rather than it's frame. I have to do it on the contentSize, because I don't want to increase the "real" size of the UIScrollView, and the content is loaded dynamically and asynchronously so I can't do it manually when I add the subviews to the UIScrollView.

Comment: Starting a bounty on this.  At the moment, the best answer I have is to iterate over the subviews and look at their frames.  I am wondering if there is a better way.  SizeThatFits: does not seem to help.

Comment: Try overriding sizeThatFits: to do the desired computation.

Comment: [Swift extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36504526/1634890)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

At the moment, this is the best I have:

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
self.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```

Comment: This method is great, BUT... for some reason, it doesn't work for me if the phone is in landscape mode. Any ideas?

Comment: This solution doesn't take into account the UIImageViews that are already present as UIScrollView subviews if scroll bars are set to show (see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664281/uiscrollview-phantom-subviews)). One way to filter these out would be to set the tag property of the subviews the user wants to include in the for loop calculation to the same non-zero value, and use an if statement to filter.

Comment: @adamjansch Or use `isKindOfClass:` in place of `tag`s. Or use: `[self.subviews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class = %@", [UILabel class]]];` - incorrect because it uses `class` and not `isKindOfClass:`, but good enough for most uses.

Answer (score 4):

If your function is called frequently, you wouldn't want to iterate over the subviews each time. Instead, whenever a subview is added, do a union of the current contentSize and the frame of the new subview.

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview {
    CGRect tmp;
    tmp.origin = CGPointZero;
    tmp.size = self.contentSize;
    tmp = CGRectUnion(tmp,subview.frame);
    self.contentSize = tmp.size;
}
```

Comment: Probably a good solution in some situations.  Unfortunately, my subviews are frequently resizing.  So in my case, this is not a good solution.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch If the subviews are frequently resized, you could add a KVO observer for `frame` or `bounds` and update `contentSize` accordingly. It would get tricky, but depending on number of subviews, may be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution here [ScrollView ContentSize](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/357), you will be able to find the sizes of the subviews and find the combined content size and also options to say whether subviews are arranged horizontally or vertically.

Here is the code from the link above :

```
@interface UIScrollView(auto_size)
- (void) adjustHeightForCurrentSubviews: (int) verticalPadding;
- (void) adjustWidthForCurrentSubviews: (int) horizontalPadding;
- (void) adjustWidth: (bool) changeWidth andHeight: (bool) changeHeight withHorizontalPadding: (int) horizontalPadding andVerticalPadding: (int) verticalPadding;
@end

@implementation UIScrollView(auto_size)
- (void) adjustWidth: (bool) changeWidth andHeight: (bool) changeHeight withHorizontalPadding: (int) horizontalPadding andVerticalPadding: (int) verticalPadding {
    float contentWidth = horizontalPadding;
    float contentHeight = verticalPadding;
    for (UIView* subview in self.subviews) {
        [subview sizeToFit];
        contentWidth += subview.frame.size.width;
        contentHeight += subview.frame.size.height;
    }

    contentWidth = changeWidth ? contentWidth : self.superview.frame.size.width;
    contentHeight = changeHeight ? contentHeight : self.superview.frame.size.height;

    NSLog(@"Adjusting ScrollView size to %fx%f, verticalPadding=%d, horizontalPadding=%d", contentWidth, contentHeight, verticalPadding, horizontalPadding);
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight);
}

- (void) adjustHeightForCurrentSubviews: (int) verticalPadding {
    [self adjustWidth:NO andHeight:YES withHorizontalPadding:0 andVerticalPadding:verticalPadding];
}

- (void) adjustWidthForCurrentSubviews: (int) horizontalPadding {
    [self adjustWidth:YES andHeight:NO withHorizontalPadding:horizontalPadding andVerticalPadding:0];
}
@end
```

Also make sure to have a look at the comments on the blog page as an alternative solution is provided.

-anoop

Answer (score 1):

I have made one function for setting content size of scrollView try it and enjoy

First of all write this function...

```
-(void)setContentSizeOfScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scroll
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;

    for(UIView * vv in [scroll subviews])
    {
        rect = CGRectUnion(rect, vv.frame);
    }

    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
}
```

then after adding all elements just call this function and pass your scroll view as argument.....

```
[self setContentSizeOfScrollView:self.YourScrollView];
```

I am 100% sure that it will work.........

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for Swift 3.0

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    var contentRect: CGRect = CGRect.zero
    for view in self.scrollView.subviews {
        debugPrint("view frame \(view.frame)")
        contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
        debugPrint("frame \(contentRect)")
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
    debugPrint("content size \(self.scrollView.contentSize)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While [William's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250140/4590902) was very useful, it didn't work perfectly since the scrollbars are also subviews of the scrollview. Turns out, the trick is to hide them before calculating the content size. Here's what the Swift 3 code would look like:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    scrollView.layoutSubviews()

    // disable scrollbars so they don't interfere during resizing
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    scrollView.contentSize = scrollView.subViewArea()

    // re-enable the scrollbars
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
}
```

You'll also need to add the following extension somewhere in your project:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func subViewArea() -> CGSize {
        var rect = CGRect.zero
        for subview in subviews {
            rect = rect.union(subview.frame)
        }

        return rect.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a UIView into the UIScrollView that has the same width and height and add all subviews to IT rather than the scrollview. Then set the clipToBounds property on the scrollview to TRUE, and call sizeToFit on your UIView. You can also set the opacity of the UIView's background to 0 making it invisible, but still showing its subviews.

Comment: I just realised that it should be the other way around: The enclosing view should be the UIView, while the inner (larger) view should be the transparent UIScrollView. Then it should work.

Comment: Are you sure, what you wrote in your answer makes sense, i had though of what you said there, but it seems a bit "unproper"

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction... I partially used the above solution for my own project at work last week. Unfortunately, sizeToFit does not seem to have any effect on the UIScrollView within the UIView. So I've manually set its contentSize after having added all subviews to it. Doing that it doesn't even need the enclosing UIView anymore.

Comment: You could use a for-loop to iterate through all of the UIScrollView's subviews and sum up their width/height-properties, then set the contentSize of the scrollView manually to that value.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 2.1, add this to your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let aggregateView = contentView.subviews.reduce(CGRect())
        { aggRect, view in aggRect.union(view.frame) }

    scrollView.contentSize = aggregateView.size

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough that union frame sizes to calculate the content size. Because sometimes, your subview needs to overlap, and sometimes you have margins between subviews. You have to know and calculate origin of subviews.

Union approach gives same content hight for A and B designs. But if you know biggest last subview, you can calculate right content hight:

[image]

**This extension can calculate the real content height.**

```
extension UIScrollView {

 func adjustContentHeight(bottomPadding: Int = 0) {

    var lastSub: CGRect = .zero
    self.subviews.forEach({
        let sub = $0.frame
        if(sub.maxY > lastSub.maxY) {
            lastSub = sub
        }
    })

    self.contentSize.height = lastSub.maxY + CGFloat(bottomPadding)
 }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 2 extension:**

Usage:

`scrollView.contentResize`
`scrollView.contentWidthResize`
`scrollView.contentHeightResize`

```
extension UIScrollView {

    ///Will resize content size to fit all subviews.
    func contentResize(){

        var w = CGFloat(0)
        var h = CGFloat(0)

        for view in self.subviews{

            let fw = view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.width
            let fh = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.height

            w = max(fw, w)
            h = max(fh, h)

        }

        contentSize = CGSize(width: w, height: h)

    }

    ///Will resize content width size to fit all subviews.
    func contentWidthResize(){

        var w = CGFloat(0)

        for view in self.subviews{

            let fw = view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.width

            w = max(fw, w)

        }

        contentSize.width = w

    }

    ///Will resize content height size to fit all subviews.
    func contentHeightResize(){

        var h = CGFloat(0)

        for view in self.subviews{

            let fh = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.height

            h = max(fh, h)

        }

        contentSize.height = h

    }

}
```

Comment: `view.w` and `view.h` are not defined mate.

Comment: @YoussefSami edited..., please consider removing  the downvote and voting  if you find it useful, thanks for the info.