# UIScrollview does not react to any touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to do a simple scroll, but the views do not move after a touch, I am not sure why, the scrollview should handle the gesture, but something might be missing. Would someone know where?

Here is the code : I create a small horizontal scroll view, with some views inside. The views appear well, I am testing it on a device for the touch :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //horizontal scroll view
    HorizScroll *ho = [[HorizScroll alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 100)];
    for ( int i=0; i<3; i++){
        MyView* mv = [[MyView alloc] init];
        [ho addSubview:mv];
    }
    //ho.zoomScale = 0.3f;
    [self.view addSubview:ho];
}





@implementation HorizScroll
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addSubview:(UIView *)view{
    [super addSubview:view];
    NSUInteger numSubviews = self.subviews.count;
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds)*(numSubviews),
                             0,
                             CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds),
                             CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) )];
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds)*(numSubviews),
                                   CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) )];
}









@implementation MyView
-(int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)from to:(int)pto {
    return (int)(from + arc4random() % (pto-from+1));
}
-(instancetype)init{
    if ( self = [super init] ){
        CGFloat red = [self getRandomNumberBetween:1 to:255];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/256.0
                                               green:[self getRandomNumberBetween:1 to:255]/256.0
                                                blue:[self getRandomNumberBetween:1 to:255]/256.0
                                               alpha:1.0];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if ( self = [super initWithFrame:frame] ){
        self.frame = CGRectMake(counterX, 0, 100, 100);
        counterX += 50;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Does HorizScroll inherit from UIScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `contentSize` of scrollview to be larger than its frame size. so add this line after `[self.view addSubview:ho]`.

```
ho.contentSize = CGSizeMake(501.f, 100.f);
```

or before `[self.view addSubview:ho]` and comment out the line:

```
[self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds)*(numSubviews),
                                CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds))];
```

which is not necessary since you can set it after all subviews are added.

Comment: One question though, why it does not work if I set a small width size for the frame, and let the setContentSize in the scroll view subclass (which will be bigger)? The scroll then does not respond. It only works with your technique so far...

Comment: It should work, you can set a breakpoint to see the final contentSize after you add ho as a subview of self.view, and compare it with the frame.

Comment: pardon my lack of knowledge :) when you set a breakpoint, where can you find the information about the frame and contentSize? EDIT: if you meant by a NSLog, the result is : `contentSize {300, 100}, frame {{0, 0}, {200, 100}}`

Comment: I don't know what is happening, right after adding the scroll view to self.view, the "addSubview" is called again a 4th and 5th time, and it sets the frame width and height to 2.5... but `MyView` is created only 3 times, and so there are only 3 views inside `ho`, which should not be calling `addSubview` again after `self.view addSubview...`

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5664311/4016786), when scrollview draws on screen, it adds two scroll indicator subviews, which can be removed by setting `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` to `NO`.

Comment: that's perfect, thank you very much, I could not find the issue :) It works fine, thanks a lot